# Adobe CQ Image Coponent fileName

Tags: adobe, aem

I created a new Adobe CQ 5.6.1 Project using the Maven archetype, then created a page component, and a `cq:Page` that uses that page component as the `sling:resourceType`. The page component has a

```
<cq:include path="par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
```

and the design for that par has the attribute

```
components="[/libs/foundation/components/image,/libs/foundation/components/download]"
```

Everything is fine, I can load the page, in the sidekick I see the Image and Download components and am able to drag them into the par.

#### The Problem

When I edit the Download component, I select a file from my file system which gets uploaded to the CRX into a `file` node. The parent of this file node gets a property called `fileName` which reflects the file name of the uploaded file.

When I edit the Image component, it behaves the same way by taking the file I selected from my file system and uploading it to a `file` node, however there is not `fileName` property set.

Looking at the dialog for each of those foundation components, I see they have a `fileNameParameter`, however in the case of the `foundation/components/image` that is just ignored. I need to persist the original upload `fileName`, how can I do this with `foundation/components/image`.

Comment: I think I once filed a bug at Adobe for this issue. I am not sure, but I think it depends on which browser and which upload mechanism you use. If I remember right, it was Firefox with the html5 uploader. You can set useHTML5="{Boolean}false" in an overlayed dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended the `html5smartimage` xtype by putting this JS script into a clientlib

```
var MyAppLib = MyAppLib || {};

MyAppLib.NamedHtml5SmartImage = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.html5.form.SmartImage, {

    constructor : function(config) {

        config = config || {};
        var defaults = {
            "transferFileName" : true
        };

        CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaults);
        MyAppLib.NamedHtml5SmartImage.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    }
});

CQ.Ext.reg("namedhtml5smartimage", MyAppLib.NamedHtml5SmartImage);
```

and then created a new component based on `foundation/components/image` and unsed my xtype `namedhtml5smartimage` in place of the `html5smartimage` in the dialog tab configuration.