# How can we extend the foundation clientlib js scripts in AEM?

Tags: aem

I want to extend the AEM foundation file fileuploadfield.js for making changes in custom image component dialog like want to display the image path and file size which author can be dragged into the dialog. It's really great-full  if any body give an idea. Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svw8D.png)

Comment: Why can't you make a new component with your own functionality enhancements? Are you changing this file just for a specific use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adobe CQ Image Coponent fileName](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925547/adobe-cq-image-coponent-filename)

Comment: @i.net, we have implemented our own image component, but here when author dragged an image into the dialog want to show image path and image size with in the dialog. Attached an image for more clear